# Check if 3D grid is filled from top to bottom

Tags: python, mesh, voxel, trimesh

I have a 3D grid for representing shapes/meshes which is represented in python using an ndarray(20,20,20) of type bool. Each element in the grid represents the presence or absence of material. I want to be able to check if a given grid represents a shape that is connected all the way from the top of the grid to the bottom. I want to be able to discard those that are either disconnected or not occupying continuous series of cells from top of the grid to the bottom.

At a later stage I convert the grids into meshes using trimesh. Is there any way to identify the above either directly in python or through trimesh?

Comment: does a diagonal count? ``1 0 0 1, 0 1 1 0 `` would this be connected

Comment: Yes that counts. Any sort of continuous top to bottom connectivity.

Comment: top to bottom means z-axis, as in the 3rd array? I think it would help if you made an example of your datastructure

Answer (score 0):

I'd first write a helper function `bucket_fill_2d()` that takes a slice with `material` info and, given a starting index `(i,j)`, bucket fills the material like in any old drawing program.

1. Introduce an empty Boolean array `connected` of the shape.
2. Set the bottom slice `True` wherever the `material` array's bottom slice is `True`.
3. Then go up one step up and `bucket_fill_2d()`, starting with every `connected` `(i,j)` from the previous step.
4. Repeat (3) until you reach the top.
5. Check if anything is `connected` at the top slice.

Note that trimesh, as the name suggests, only supports *triangular* cells.